# Check if the table "keysystem" value that was inserted has been used or no

Tags: php, c++

I'm making a auth for my program and here is the code I used for a simple login:

```
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM keysystem WHERE keysystem = '$keysystem'");
        $cnt2 = $query->num_rows;


        if($cnt2 > 0)
        {
            echo "GOOD";
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "BAD";
        }
```

for C++ I use this:

```
string DownloadString(string URL) {
    HINTERNET interwebs = InternetOpenA("Mozilla/5.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    HINTERNET urlFile;
    string rtn;
    if (interwebs) {
        urlFile = InternetOpenUrlA(interwebs, URL.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (urlFile) {
            char buffer[2000];
            DWORD bytesRead;
            do {
                InternetReadFile(urlFile, buffer, 2000, &bytesRead);
                rtn.append(buffer, bytesRead);
                memset(buffer, 0, 2000);
            } while (bytesRead);
            InternetCloseHandle(interwebs);
            InternetCloseHandle(urlFile);
            string p = replaceAll(rtn, "|n", "\r\n");
            return p;
        }
    }
    InternetCloseHandle(interwebs);
    string p = replaceAll(rtn, "|n", "\r\n");
    return p;
}

string login = DownloadString("http://website.com/handler.php?action=login&keysystem=" + license).c_str();

    if (login.find("890") != std::string::npos)
    {
        char buffer[256];
            print::set_text("\n  Successfully logged in!\n\n", Green);

            printf("\n\n");
            Beep(666, 200);
            Sleep(2000);
    }

    else if (login.find("880") != std::string::npos)
    {
        print::set_text("\n  Failed to log in! ", Red);
        Beep(666, 200);
        Sleep(2000);
        exit(0);
    }
```

It works fine but I want to check if the key is already used by someone or not.

Comment: i accidentally replaced the GOOD WITH 980 and BAD with 880

Comment: Add a field to `keysystem` table like `is_used` and filter by this field too.

Comment: how will i select the table and check the exact key is used or no

Comment: `SELECT * FROM keysystem WHERE keysystem = '$keysystem' and is_used = false` for example.

Comment: aah im kinda getting it now if i have a issue ill let you know and thank you so much for helping me

Answer (score 0):

To understand if your key is used you can add a field, which stores if key is used of not, e.g. `is_used` with `true` \ `false` values.

Then your query becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM keysystem WHERE keysystem = '$keysystem' and is_used = false
```

Of course, don't forget to set field `is_used` to `true` when someone starts to use it.